# "Despite the fact that" or "Even though" - Which is more stronger and emphatic?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I know that "even though" is more stronger than "although". The former *"makes the contrast between the main and subordinate clauses stronger or more emphatic."* I know they all are used to show contrast.

Source 1: [Is there a difference between “although” and “even though”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/162642/is-there-a-difference-between-although-and-even-though/162655)
Source 2: [Despite vs although](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/214177/despite-vs-although)

In an academic piece, I have the following sentence:

> ***Even though*** Scarlett and Melissa both worked at the same firm and had equivalent work histories, Scarlett receives 16 more weeks of EI benefits (for a total of 30 weeks) than Melissa.

Or

> ***Despite the fact that*** Scarlett and Melissa ...

Question: Between "even though" and "despite the fact that", which one gives the sentence a stronger contrast?

---

Background: Two unemployed workers who have equivalent work histories and who worked at the same firm prior to layoff receive widely varied unemployment benefits due to some program rules. In my sentence, I am trying to put emphasis on the unfair treatment of such workers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that a native reader will perceive any material difference in meaning, or indeed any difference at all, between "even though" and "despite the fact that."

English can express subtleties in many ways. Those ways are not always lexical. You can make your point clearly in probably many different ways. For example,

> That S received a benefit more than double that of M, despite identical work histories at the same employer, exemplifies the gross inequities caused by some program rules.

Trying to make your point through the distinction, if there even be one, between "despite" and "even though" is not nearly as effective as English allows.